# Shell script, AppleScript Mac OS X

Tags: shell-script, applescript, checksum, java-applet

I’m trying to copy embedded metadata from image files and write to a `.txt` file, as well as generate MD5 and SHA1 checksums for the same images to be added to the same `.txt` file.

I can run this action via the terminal command line:

```
exiftool (Directory)>FileName.txt; openssl sha1 (individual files)>>FileName.txt; MD5 (individual files)>>FileName.txt
```

What I want to do is create a script(?) that I can drop a Directory of images into that will take away having to input those paths three different times in the terminal. I have seen applets and other scripts act similar. I just don't know enough about it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible. Here is something similar I did using VLC to play all files in a folder.

It is using Automator to create a *Service* which appears as an option when you right click a folder in Finder.

[image]

The shell script code, if you go this way, I'll leave up to you to work out...you already know the commands you need to run, should be easy to work it out.

Just a final note. Your three commands take time so it will be hard to know where things are at - except for CPU usage. One suggestion would be to look into using addon libraries that provide progress dialog boxes like ASObjC Runner.

Good luck.

PS: This may be helpful...
https://stackoverflow.com/q/1857050/348694